# Annoying Bootstrap Menu issue in Safari

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, safari, mobile-safari

I am having a really annoying issue with a Bootstrap Menu in Safari on OSX / IOS devices.

If you have a look at this page:

Link Removed

In chrome or Firefox you will see how it should look, however if you look in Safari, the middle section of the menu isn't flush to the top. This causes issues when viewing on an iPad as the text overlaps. It should look like this:

[How it should look on tablet http://www.nick-harper.co.uk/howitshouldlook.gif](http://www.nick-harper.co.uk/howitshouldlook.gif)

However, it is like this:

[How it looks http://www.nick-harper.co.uk/ipad.gif](http://www.nick-harper.co.uk/ipad.gif)

I have tried various different things but can't seem to figure out what causes it specifically in Safari.

Are there any common issues that could cause it I am missing?

Comment: You don't need to use absolute position if you want to achieve the effect. Also your CSS is too !important.

Comment: Thanks, I have managed to sort this on the tablet. It is just the Safari desktop view now where it shows different to Chrome :(

Comment: Thanks, I have resolved this on the tablets etc. Just need to make the middle menu go to the top in Safari like it does in Chrome. Where is the absolute position?

Comment: I won't help much because I don't have a Mac. I presume that it is caused because of `position:unset` – it's an invalid value. Try `position:static`, which is the default value.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to make it a bit neater on the mobile version, however on the desktop it should go into 3 columns, on Chrome the middle menu sits at the top, but on safari it sits alongside to the right still.

Comment: Why do you use `float:left` on `ul`, `li`s and `a`s? That might be the problem. Set `float:none`.

Comment: Thanks, I added it to none to one of them and it fixed it! It wont let me mark it as an answer though :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80823/discussion-between-user2572639-and-andale).

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing comments under the question, the problem was `float:left`. It made height of a few elements to be equal 0. Also `position:unset` is invalid so `position:absolute` from another selector was in use.